# handle list view with check box and search implemention

Tags: android, listview, searchview, checkboxlist

i have a list view which has check box on each row and i`ve implemented a serch view to search in the list view. the problem is that when i search the list view and select item at postion X from the modifided list, delete the text from the search view i see the original list with the item checked in position X.

Example - list of a,b,c....z .

i can see 5 items on the list:

A
B
C
D
E

then search for z so i see only Z and check it. then i delete Z and see A-E again and A is checked.

this is my main:

```
public class AddRoomatesScreen extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
SharedPreferences preferences;
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<String>();
MyAdapter adapter;
Button btnSelect;
String apartmentnumber;
SearchView searchView;
ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_roomate);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("appData", 0);
    int apartmentNumber = preferences.getInt("apartmentNumber", 0);
    apartmentnumber = Integer.toString(apartmentNumber);
    getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(nameList,contactList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    // adding
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSelectedContacts);
    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i<adapter.mCheckStates.size(); i++){
                Contact contact = (adapter.contactsListCopy.get(adapter.mCheckStates.keyAt(i)));
                new addRoommate().execute(apartmentnumber, contact.getPhoneNumber());
            }
            preferences = getSharedPreferences("appData", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("roomatesLoadedFromDB", false);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.toggle(arg2);
}

public void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        nameList.add(name);
        phoneList.add(phoneNumber);
        contactList.add(new Contact(name,phoneNumber));
    }

    phones.close();
}
```

this is my adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,Filterable {
    private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView  tv;
    CheckBox cb;
    ValueFilter filter;
    ArrayList<Contact> contactsList;
    ArrayList<Contact> contactsListCopy;

    MyAdapter(List<String> nameList , ArrayList<Contact> contactsList) {
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(contactsList.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) AddRoomatesScreen.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.contactsList = contactsList;
        this.contactsListCopy = this.contactsList;
        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactsListCopy.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contactsListCopy.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        Contact contact = contactsListCopy.get(position);
        tv.setText(contact.getName());
        cb.setTag(position);
        cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {

        mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
            filter = new ValueFilter();
        }
            return filter;

    }

        private class ValueFilter extends Filter {


            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    ArrayList<Contact> temp = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
                        Contact c = contactList.get(i);
                        if ((c.getName().toString())
                                .contains(constraint.toString())) {
                            temp.add(c);
                        }
                    }
                    results.count = temp.size();
                    results.values = temp;
                } else {
                    results.count = contactList.size();
                    results.values = contactList;
                }
                return results;

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                contactsListCopy = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }


}
```

this is my model:

```
public class Contact{
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String name;

    public Contact(String name , String phoneNumber){
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

You can use the ID from the cursor as your unique id.

This code would go with the code originally posted below.

Add id to your Contact class:

```
public class Contact{
    private long id;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String name;

    public Contact(long id, String name , String phoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

This is how you get the ID from the cursor:

```
public void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        long id = phones.getLong(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        nameList.add(name);
        phoneList.add(phoneNumber);
        contactList.add(new Contact(id, name, phoneNumber));
    }

    phones.close();
}
```

Your `mCheckStates` in the adapter changes to:

```
    private LongSparseArray<Boolean> mCheckStates;
```

Some of the original answer below has been changed to match the `long` type used for id.

---

The problem is that your `mCheckStates` boolean map isn't kept in sync with `contactsListCopy` as it is filtered.

- You filtered on Z so Z is now item 0,
- You checked Z which sets position 0 as checked,
- You redisplay the whole list.  Now A is position 0 so it shows as checked.

Instead of tracking checked positions, you need to track checked contacts. To do that, you need to use the unique ID from the contact record.

Here's the changes you need to make:

Make your adapter use the unique id:

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return contactsListCopy.get(position).getId(); 
    }
```

Now your activity has to use the unique id instead of position:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        adapter.toggle(arg3);
    }
```

In your adapter `getView()`, you have to use the ID for the check box now

```
    cb.setTag(contact.getId());
    cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(contact.getId(), false));
```

I would change some other methods just to avoid confusion:

```
    public boolean isChecked(long id) {
        return mCheckStates.get(id, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(long id, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(id, isChecked);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggle(long id) {
        setChecked(id, !isChecked(id));
    }
```

Comment: Great! Updated answer.

Comment: my unique id was the phone number which is a string and your solution didnt work. what i did is a int id=0 in the main activity; and when i inizialize the list i passed it to the constructor and then incremnted it by 1. but i think its not a good solution. do you have better solution?

Comment: You have a unique ID in the cursor.  I've updated my answer again.

Comment: @krislarson Hii. I am facing the problem. So  I modified the code what you said. But i am getting this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.util.LongSparseArray.get(long, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference" at this place cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(contact.getId(), false));

Comment: Please when u get back to stack overflow could you please respond to this comment.

Comment: Looks like you didn't instantiate the `LongSparseArray`.  I left that code out of my example.  You could for example try `private LongSparseArray<Boolean> mCheckStates = new LongSparseArray<>();`  If you are still having problems, please ask a new question so that the entire community can have a look at it and examine your specific code.

Comment: @krislarson Hii. ok it solved. When i selected the contacts and click the button it shows this error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference". at mCustomAdapter.mCheckedStates.get(i). So i wrote like this in adapter class is "mCheckedStates = new LongSparseArray<>(ContactList.size());" And again it shows the same error after assigning some value. When i print the size of the mCustomAdapter.mCheckedStates.size it show the correct value how many contacts i selected but when getting value it shows the error. How to solve that?

Comment: Do you know why it is occurring?

Comment: @vijju Make sure the `i` value in `mCheckedStates.get(i)` is a Contact id and not an item position.  You might be using the `arg2` parameter from `onItemClick()`, which is the position.  You should use the `arg3` parameter which is now the Contact id because of the `getItemId()` implementation.  Again, if you are still having problems, please ask a new question so that the entire community can have a look at it and examine your specific code.  Without seeing your code we can only make guesses.  Seeing the code helps us solve the problem.

Comment: i already asked a question this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827308/error-java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-boolea?noredirect=1#comment92571426_52827308